# Use regex to get array of values from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I am trying to get all the words comes with inside bracket in  string using javascript but i am not get clear idea. please help me.

**Input**

```
"  (  [Field1]  +  [Field2]  )    +    (  [Field3]  -  [Field4]  )  "
```

**Required Output**

```
["Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, tried some basic regex yet?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew I will start to learn regex. thanks

Comment: Starting to learn by doing nothing will not help. Do all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), read through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, have a look at [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com).

Comment: wiktor -- thanks for your effort I will do.

Comment: Well, regexone.com will do for a start :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) that select specific part of string by regex. Note that the `\w+` matches word characters.

```js
var str =  "  (  [Field1]  +  [Field2]  )    +    (  [Field3]  -  [Field4]  )  ";
var result = str.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(result);
```